# surface view not drawing anthing ... frame skipped message

Tags: android, surfaceview

```
public class CannonView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    CannonThread cannonThread;
    private Paint blockerPaint;

    public CannonView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        blockerPaint = new Paint();
        blockerPaint.setStrokeWidth(10.0f);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        cannonThread = new CannonThread(holder);
        cannonThread.running(true);
        cannonThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        cannonThread.running(false);
        while (retry) {

            try {
                cannonThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }

        }

    }

    private class CannonThread extends Thread {

        boolean setRunning;
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

        public CannonThread(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            setRunning = true;
            surfaceHolder = holder;

        }

        public void running(boolean isRunning) {
            setRunning = isRunning;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas canvas = null;

            while (setRunning) {

                try {

                    canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();


                        synchronized (surfaceHolder) {

                            canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100, blockerPaint);

                        }
                } finally {
                    if (canvas != null)
                        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Although above code is very simple
 but it is not drawing anything on my activity ..
Logcat says i am doing too much work on main thread ..62 frame skipped ..
Please help

Comment: You never call setColor on Paint.   I don't know what the default alpha value is.  Maybe it is transparent.  Set the color AGRB and see if it draws your line.

Comment: no it didn't work .its complaning that too much work on main thread 52 frames skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this isn't my style of coding, so I decided that you need to simplify things a bit. You used the android api guides but they suck.

Watch the following videos and you should be fine.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUmId0rwsBQ&list=SP2F07DBCDCC01493A&index=67

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wy907WZFiA&list=SP2F07DBCDCC01493A

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMcYbf9Hhe4&list=SP2F07DBCDCC01493A

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yowNavIDzzE&list=SP2F07DBCDCC01493A

Comment: I think I found the problem. In surface destroyed, your making retry = false. That means the while loop will stop. But then your making it true again so it keeps on looping.

Comment: Wait a minute... I had the exact same problem. It happens when something in the code keeps on looping. Follow along with the video and you should be fine.